# Unable to Download csv file using werbdriver + java

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I need to downlond csv file from my application. In my application there is table which contains rows and on right click of that row it display download option , on click on of that download it displays windows popup with open and save button.

To download csv from my application i have written below code but which is not working :(

```
WebDriver driver;
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(); 
profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "c:\\test"); 
profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2); 

profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/csv");  
profile.setPreference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", false); 
profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false); 
driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
     driver.get("Application link");  

     // Steps to click on Download file
```

Please Help.![enter image description here][1]

Comment: At which step is it failing ?

Comment: Have a read of this: http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/index.php/2012/07/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt/

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
profile.setPreference("browser.download.downloadDir", "c:\\test");
profile.setPreference("browser.download.defaultFolder", "c:\\test");
```

In addition - csv can come in many content types, not just text/csv..
Try using Firefox addon like HTTP headers to see the exact type the response.

Comment: +lttiel can you help me download the csv file? which addon it is not clear in your answer.

Comment: see http headers installation and usage example here: https://support.zscaler.com/hc/en-us/articles/201513385-How-do-I-capture-HTTP-headers-on-Mozilla-Firefox-